# merge the json with same length

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have two set of json data I want to merge In json1 I have `username,subject,Geo`.In json2 I have `week,monthinwords`.I want to merge `username,subject,GEo,week,monthinwords`

expected output

```
[
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
            "Geo":"Europe",
            "week":"Week 3",
            "monthinwords":"July"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
            "Geo":"Europe",
            "week":"Week 3",
            "monthinwords":"July"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
            "Geo":"Europe",
            "week":"Week 3",
            "monthinwords":"July"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
            "Geo":"Europe",
            "week":"Week 2",
            "monthinwords":"July"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Test Automation Discussion - Peleton International",
            "Geo":"Europe",
            "week":"Week 1",
            "monthinwords":"July"
         }
         
      ]
```

```js
var json1 = [
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
            "Geo":"Europe"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
            "Geo":"Europe"
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
            "Geo":"Europe"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
            "Geo":"Europe"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Test Automation Discussion - Peleton International",
            "Geo":"Europe"
         }
         
      ];
var json2 = [
         {
            "week":"Week 3",
            "monthinwords":"July"
         },
         {
            "week":"Week 3",
            "monthinwords":"July"
         },
         {
            "week":"Week 3",
            "monthinwords":"July"
         },
         {
            "week":"Week 2",
            "monthinwords":"July"
         },
         {
            "week":"Week 1",
            "monthinwords":"July"
         }  ];


var obj3 = Object.assign(json1, json2);
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj3));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
var json1 = [
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
            "Geo":"Europe"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
            "Geo":"Europe"
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
            "Geo":"Europe"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",
            "Geo":"Europe"
            
         },
         {
            "UserName":"Sarathy Devaraju",
            "Subject":"Test Automation Discussion - Peleton International",
            "Geo":"Europe"
         }
         
      ];
var json2 = [
         {
            "week":"Week 3",
            "monthinwords":"July"
         },
         {
            "week":"Week 3",
            "monthinwords":"July"
         },
         {
            "week":"Week 3",
            "monthinwords":"July"
         },
         {
            "week":"Week 2",
            "monthinwords":"July"
         },
         {
            "week":"Week 1",
            "monthinwords":"July"
         }  ];

const result = json1.reduce((acc, rec, index) => {
  return [ ...acc, { ...rec, ...json2[index] } ]
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just map and merge the two:

```js
const json1=[{UserName:"Sarathy Devaraju",Subject:"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",Geo:"Europe"},{UserName:"Sarathy Devaraju",Subject:"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",Geo:"Europe"},{UserName:"Sarathy Devaraju",Subject:"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",Geo:"Europe"},{UserName:"Sarathy Devaraju",Subject:"Multi-layered Testing Discussion",Geo:"Europe"},{UserName:"Sarathy Devaraju",Subject:"Test Automation Discussion - Peleton International",Geo:"Europe"}];

const json2=[{week:"Week 3",monthinwords:"July"},{week:"Week 3",monthinwords:"July"},{week:"Week 3",monthinwords:"July"},{week:"Week 2",monthinwords:"July"},{week:"Week 1",monthinwords:"July"}];


const result = json1.map((el, i) => ({...el, ...json2[i]}));
console.log(result);
```